# Consuming CakePHP web service in Android with null response

Tags: android, json, cakephp

I'm having a big trouble.

I was making an Android app that consume a local web service made with cakephp. Locally it works perfect, but now, I put these web services in production server, and when I'm testing the Android app from the emulator I'm getting null response.

My code is this:

```
      InputStream is = null;
  String result = "";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters= 
            new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "hello"));

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
```

I notice that the parameters arrive as null content on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me when I'm consuming a CakePHP service. responseBody contains the response string, which is JSON in my case.

```
public static JSONObject httpPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient(); //new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    String responseBody = null;
    JSONObject jObject = null;
    try {
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        jObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Oops
    }  catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return jObject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a code more perfect than mine, now the webservices are running in my app, I guess that was some firewall or other stuff in the middle that was interfering. Thank you very much for your contribution